# help with accepts_nested_attributes_for in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :street, postal_code
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :work_address, :class_name => 'Address'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :work_address

  def initialize(params={})
    params[:address] = Address.new
    params[:work_address] = Address.new
    super
  end
end
```

When trying to create a Person:

```
person = {
  "address_attributes" => {:street => "foo", :postal_code => "45632-963"}
  "work_address_attributes" => {:street => "bar", :postal_code => "45632-964"}
}
Person.create(person)
```

I got a person object with address fields filled, but the work_adress fields are blank. However, it works when I try:

```
p.work_address_attributes = {:street => "bar", :postal_code => "45632-964"}
```

In my view, I have the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |form| %>
...
<%= form.fields_for :address do |address| %>
  <%= address.text_field :street %>
  <%= address.text_field :postal_code %>
<% end %>

<%= form.fields_for :work_address do |work_address| %>
  <%= work_address.text_field :street %>
  <%= work_address.text_field :postal_code %>
<% end %>

<%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting out the line in your initialize function that sets `params[:work_address]` to a new Address object?  You shouldn't need to set it if you're using nested attributes.  If you really need those two lines, I would change them to something like this:

```
params[:work_address] = Address.new if params[:work_address_attributes].nil?
```

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` should handle that logic for you. Perhaps your address object is overriding what you are passing in the hash?

Comment: No. my address object doesnt override nothing. I proposed solution works fine. I had tested and concluded I dont need this code in constructor at all. But when I remove it, the `form.fields_for :address` view code doesn't render anything. any solution for this?